# Issues usng regex on a split string from a field then using case conditions based on boolean result

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Hello I would like to use a case statement with redshift based I can parse from a regular expression then make a decision from there.

```sql
       CASE
         WHEN regexp_like (SPLIT_PART(eel_line,',',21), '^1z.*') THEN SPLIT_PART(eel_line,',',21)
         ELSE SPLIT_PART(eel_line,',',18)
       END AS trackno,
```

The error I am receiving: function regexp_like(text, "unknown") does not exist;

I would like SPLIT_PART(eel_line,',',21) when the regular expression matches, otherwise I would like another index. As seen in the code, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedShift is based on Postgres.  Use the `~` for pattern matching:

```
WHEN SPLIT_PART(eel_line, ',', 21) ~ '^1z.*') THEN SPLIT_PART(eel_line, ',', 21)
```

You don't need the `.*`.  Actually, you don't need regular expressions at all:

```
WHEN SPLIT_PART(eel_line, ',', 21) LIKE '1z%') THEN SPLIT_PART(eel_line, ',', 21)
```